# Memory allocation by content type in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to capture the memory allocation by content type (example: music, video, etc). How can this be done on iPhone?

Comment: can u be clear about which type of memory allocation

Comment: @krishna: Thanks, Memory allocated for music files, video files etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044147/memory-limit-and-ios-memory-allocation-in-iphone-sdk is this usefull

Comment: I want to fetch the total size of the music files available in the iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the file path then you can get the size of that:

```
int fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:someFilePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

See: https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport

Comment: Thanks krishna, But i am not getting the file path only, Where exactly the music files get stored in ios5

Comment: wait for 10 min i will provide u

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport this will help to get the path