# What's the maximum size an iphone can create an image composition?

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-image

I've seen other questions asking about the maximum image size that can be loading into a view, but I'm asking how big an image can the iphone compose and save to photo gallery? I've tried a couple of pic frame apps and the biggest I've made on an iphone 4 is 2400x2400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from iOS 4.0 you can use ALAssetsLibrary class to write images to standard iOS image library. According documentation there are no words about any limitations to image size. Probably it depends on RAM memory usage which is required to handle as large image as possible. This post can be useful as well [iOS memory allocation - how much memory can be used in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044147/memory-limit-and-ios-memory-allocation-in-iphone-sdk)