# How much memory can an iPhone app take up for iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, memory

I am creating an app and it uses about 30 MB of memory.  Will this make the iPhone 4 crash?  Also, what are the recommended limits for an app's memory usage on later models (e.g. iPhone 4s, 5 and 5s).  Thanks!

Comment: @developer3466402 code formatting is for _code_. Please don't use it to highlight terms in a question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Comment: sorry, I was doing this way for some time but consider your reputations I guess I am really wrong. I will avoid this practice then.

Comment: It's not your fault if people are wrongly approving the edits :) How else will you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine. There aren't any "recommended limits", per se, although you may find the answers to this question helpful: [ios app maximum memory budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887248/ios-app-maximum-memory-budget).

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not make **iPhone** crash. If your app uses excessive memory, iOS will shut down your app. Also, see this: [iOS memory allocation - how much memory can be used in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044147/memory-limit-and-ios-memory-allocation-in-iphone-sdk)