# What is "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted" in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking-2

I am tried to make iOS Application using `AFNetworking` in `UITableView`. TableView loads 20 datas like Twitter's timeline.

When it loads over 80 datas, Xcode shows spending about 70MB memory and console shows

```
"Received memory warning."
```

And

```
**"error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted".**
```

What is this and How do I treat this error?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: similar question marked as dupe but offers potential solution not captured here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651171/ios-error-in-connection-block-invoke-2-connection-interrupted

Comment: In my case I have called closer function in timer.

Answer (score 8):

**Reason:** When you load more data which contains above 70 mb  will get crash.

**Sol:** Load data (EG:)40 only at a time. Then load another (EG:)40 next time by fetching data from web service. Fetch (EG)40 data by hitting service each time & reload tableview using [pull to refresh concept](http://www.appcoda.com/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-empty/).

- 260 MB of ram  (iPad 2)
- 170-180MB of ram on devices with 512 Mb of ram total (iPhone 4, iPod touch 4g)
- 40-80MB of ram on devices that have 256 MB of ram (iPad, iPhone 3gs, iPod touch 3g)
- 25 MB on device with only 128MB of ram (IPhone 3g, iPhone 2g, iPod touch 1g-2g)

Refer following links to know about memory leakage:

1. [Max Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887248/ios-app-maximum-memory-budget)
2. [Memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044147/memory-limit-and-ios-memory-allocation-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to read it. Could you tell me why only 40 data can be fetched? If you have some references which mention "40" data, please tell me.(´・ω・`)

Comment: When you hit bulk data at a time it occurs memory issues & gets crash

Comment: Are there other reasons this might happen? Having this same issue, but memory doesn't appear to be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486001/ios-error-in-connection-block-invoke-2-connection-interrupted-but-app-only

Comment: This answer only tells us why the "Recieved memory warning." error happens.

Does anyone have an answer as to why the "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted" happens, my question got flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @JamesWolfe same problem as you, did you find an answer?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I tried posting a unique question about this but it got marked as a duplicate for this question, I don't think the user who reported it read past the title.