# error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm receiving this error when presenting a UITableView on top of a ViewController.

The issue only occurs on iPad, not on any other physical iOS devices or simulator.

Memory stays under 16MB, and there are no networking calls. Testing on iPad Air 2 running iOS 9.3.4, using Xcode 7.3.1

People have said this is a repeat question but the other two questions regarding this have no resolution, and are getting erroneously marked as duplicates.

Links to potential duplicates:

[What is "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted" in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372330/what-is-error-in-connection-block-invoke-2-connection-interrupted-in-ios)

[iOS: error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651171/ios-error-in-connection-block-invoke-2-connection-interrupted)

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, an reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem? Can you provide links to the other answers that you've researched and which are not applicable here? (It's helpful to narrow down the problem.)

Comment: I added the links, but I can't give a reproducible example of the problem because I'm not sure what's causing it, and I don't think it makes sense to post hundreds of lines of code. The other questions say it may be due to memory warnings or networking, but I stated above that I'm not having an issue with either.