# iOS: "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted" but app only uses < 20 MB of memory

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

A simple app with only a single view controller, loading only 5 lines of text, generates the following error: `error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted`

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372330/what-is-error-in-connection-block-invoke-2-connection-interrupted-in-ios) suggests the problem is memory, but according to the Xcode Memory Report, the app only uses between 10.7 MB - 18.1 MB of memory -- falling well below the threshold outlined in the SO post.

What else could cause this error?

Comment: is it about network connection? tcp?

Comment: @heximal no network connections, at this stage only presenting five strings in an array in a simple view controller :)

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: It still happens in 2021, but I don't know why. Anybody has any ideas?